# Minimise winform without blocking Outlook functionality

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, vsto, customtaskpane

I am working on a `vsto` plugin in which I've created a Form(WinForm) that has fields for long text that user has to copy from previous mails. Now, the issue i am facing is, whenever I minimise the winform, the whole Outlook gets minimised. And when I try to open the outlook application from taskbar, it goes to form again.

Is there a way where user can minimise the Form and work on outlook application independently?
For example, he/she might need to scroll through few mails to get some values of field in the winform more than one time, so they minimise the form, fetch the long text, then open the form again and paste it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a task pane instead of a floating window - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-task-panes?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp